# Getting the source code instead of the actual website

Tags: php, android

I was developing a code to read data from a PHP website and I solved the problem in this question [Cannot connect to PHP using android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240282/cannot-connect-to-php-using-android-application). Now my problem is that when i debugged the code i found that it is returning the source code of the page and not the actual page.

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Node ID</th>
<th>Temperature</th>
<th>Humidity</th>
</tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
```

I want to only get the (1,2,3) in this table.

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean - the source code (html) IS the actual page. Or are you seeing php tags etc??

Comment: check the question again i updated it

Comment: That's an error. PHP could not connect to its database using those login details. If you have supplied them, try using the proper login details and retry. Otherwise you're pretty much screwed!

Comment: That means your php code is wrong. Looks like your mysql details are incorrect.

Comment: Yes I know I am working from home right now and I am not connected to the databse. But I am asking about a way to get the values from the source code

Comment: That's not source code, but you shouldn't be able to see this on a live service - errors should be configured off in a live environment. Turn them off and use the web server's logs instead.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand you, what values are you trying to get? If the php code is a sort of basic api access point, for your java to query the database, then you need to return data in a way it can be  easily parsed, eg JSON or XML.

Comment: But without seeing the php code, im only guessing

Comment: I connected to the database now and updated the question with the output i get when i read from the php file